# React Select Async places the cursor(caret) at the end of the placeholder when input is focused

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using React Async Select and I found out that by default it places the cursor(caret) at the end of the placeholder when the input is focused. 
How can I place the cursor at the beginning? I did not find any prop that I can pass to select component to achieve that behavior.  Here's my AsyncSelect:

```
  <AsyncSelect
            styles={StyledSearchBar}
            name="search-patients"
            placeholder="Search by Last, First"
            noOptionsMessage={this.noOptionsMessage}
            loadingMessage={this.loadingMessage}
            loadOptions={this.promiseOptions}
            components={{Option: this.renderOption}}
            onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
            controlShouldRenderValue={false}
          />
```

Comment: If you check the documentation examples [here](https://react-select.com/async) the caret is well placed at the beginning. Can you provide a live example of your issue through https://codesandbox.io/ or any other platform ? Thank you

Comment: @Laura I saw the documentation samples and all of them had the cursor in the beginning. I figured out the problem but not sure why it does that. For the placeholder I was setting a color like so "placeholder: () => ({color: colors.greyLight})". For some reason it was not liking it. I removed it and added color using a class.

Comment: I have got into the same problem today. Going to check about the css you have mentioned.